# How does one set up API on a locally hosted server

Tags: ubuntu, wordpress

I am setting up a personal Wordpress site and want to be able to post to it from other sites... the common request being for my "API Key".

When creating a site on Wordpress.com for example, and API key is sent to you by mail, but surely it should be relatively simple, (if not just an address on the local site to point to,) to have one for a personal server (ubuntu server)?

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing two sets of APIs. The WordPress.com API key is used for accessing certain WordPress.com hosted services, like the Akismet spam filter and their statistics plugin.

There's also the various APIs WordPress.com and .org support for actually posting and managing blog entries. [They are documented here.](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) **These do not require an API key**, they use your username and password.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.support.wordpress.com/api-keys/ seems to talk a little about it.  It seems to imply that you need to get your key from the main site even if you host it locally.

Which is, well, odd.

Comment: it's not odd - it's a wordpress-generated key that's used to authenticate against some of their hosted services: they ensure it's unique

Comment: From what I understand, though, he wants access to his local wordpress install, not the hosted one.  It seems to me that there should be an API key for the local site which would not require using wordpress.com at all.

Comment: There's no API key for posting to a WordPress installation. It uses XMLRPC and the user's normal credentials.